# Netty SslHandler throws IllegalReferenceCountException

Tags: java, networking, client-server, netty

I'm writing client-server application using using netty 4.0.36.Final

One of test engineers encountered this problem on client side:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:418)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:962)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:371)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:101)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1072)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:904)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:387)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Channel pipeline:

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast(sslContext.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
    pipeline.addLast(new AsnMessageDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new AsnMessageEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast(dataChannelHandler);
}
```

At some point I add another handler to pipeline:

```
channel.pipeline().addFirst("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(180, 0, 0));
```

There are two `ChannelInboundHandler` 's

```
public class AsnMessageDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsnMessageDecoder.class);
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    DERCoder coder = Asn.getDERCoder();
    coder.disableEncoderDebugging();
    coder.disableDecoderDebugging();
    coder.enableEncoderConstraints();
    coder.enableDecoderConstraints();
    coder.enableAutomaticEncoding();
    coder.enableAutomaticDecoding();
    coder.enableContainedValueEncoding();
    coder.enableContainedValueDecoding();
    try (ByteBufInputStream is = new ByteBufInputStream(in)) {
        out.add(coder.decode(is, new Message()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to decode message", e);
    }
}
```

And another one:

```
abstract class BaseChannelHandler<T extends ChannelContext> extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Message> {
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

private final T channelContext;
private final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration;
private final Writer writer;
private final ClientService service;

BaseChannelHandler(T channelContext,
                   ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration,
                   Writer writer,
                   ClientService service) {
    this.channelContext = channelContext;
    this.clientConfiguration = clientConfiguration;
    this.writer = writer;
    this.service = service;
}

@Override
public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    log.debug("{} channelRegistered", getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    log.debug("{} channelActive", getClass().getSimpleName());
    channelContext.connectState();
}

@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Message msg) throws Exception {
    log.debug("{} channelRead0 msg = {}", getClass().getSimpleName(), msg);
    channelContext.handleMessage(msg);
    if (clientConfiguration.isWritingOutputEnabled()) {
        writer.writeXml(msg);
    }
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    log.error(getClass().getSimpleName() + " exceptionCaught", cause);
    ctx.close();
    service.stop();
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    log.debug("{} channelInactive", getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    log.debug("{} channelUnregistered", getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
    if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
        ctx.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I can't repdoduce problem. On my local machine it works fine. Looking in wirweshark doesn't give me any hint. It looks like normal disconnect. 
I'm not quite sure what to do next to localize this problem. Can you give me some advice on next step to solve this problem?

Comment: I would suspect you not correct increment the reference count in one of your handlers. Can you show your pipeline and custom handlers ?

Comment: Hi, Norman. Thanks for reply. I can't provide code of my hadlers, but I can show you pipeline.I eddited initial message. Looking on stack trace it seems that this read event went through IdleStateHandler and throw exception in SslHandler. Both are netty's classes and custom handlers doesn't participated. Could it be a netty SslHandler bug?

Comment: Sure it could be a netty bug but I think its unlikely. While the exception happens in the SslHandler it may just only shown up there as it is the one that still has a reference to the buffer and try to use it. I suspect you double-release a buffer somehow. So please show me you `ChannelInboundHandler` (and sub-classes)

Comment: I added two `ChannelInboundHandler` used in pipeline.

Comment: As you can see I don't try to release any buffer at all =)

Comment: I suspect that it's a netty bug because this buffer is allocated in `SslHandler::unwrap` method. And I can't release it in my code. https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/netty-4.0.36.Final/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.java#L967

Comment: wow I just noticed you running a super old version of netty so maybe try upgrade first to 4.0.56.Final ? Also 4.0.x is EOL and 4.1.x is the one you should use ;) Please report back once done.

Comment: Switched to 4.1.24.Final - works fine. Problem doesn't reproduce.

Comment: Awesome... thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like this was a bug in the netty version (which was quite old). Upgrading to 4.1.24.Final fixed it.